# Prevent automatic updates

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible for an app (downloaded from the Android Market) to check whether it's set for Automatic Updates and, if so, disable that option?

I've looked at `PackageManager` and various associated package classes but can't find anything.

There's nothing nefarious about this - it's a niche app in beta testing and I've advised users to disable automatic updates for various reasons but I think some haven't done this and I'd like to force it for the beta phase of testing at least.

Comment: I think in app there is no configuration to disable this.

Comment: @thinksteep: Thanks, I'm beginning to come to that conclusion myself. I still can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Well, i think you will have to query the Android Market to get/set that kinda information. Does Android Market app expose any such APIs? I don't think so.

Comment: Here's someone that has tried to query Android Market Server - http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ It's an overkill but looks like there is a way to achieve what you want :)

Comment: @user693959: Thanks, I came to the conclusion that it's actually the Android Market app which has the setting to allow automatic updates or not. I wasn't thinking straight when I assumed it was an attribute of the installed package or similar. I've now added code to the app to warn the user if they have an version which needs an update at the server end. Thanks for your time, that link may be useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that it's actually the Android Market app which has the setting to allow automatic updates or not. I've left the question just in case anybody else is looking for a similar answer.